# How to SUM hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to sum hours, minutes and seconds, using Sql Server 2008

The Field contains time values only.

**Input**

```
ID       HORA_S  
--  ----------------------
1   1899-12-30 18:22:50.000
2   1899-12-30 18:22:50.000
3   1899-12-30 18:30:50.000
```

**Output**

```
HOURS  MINUTES SECONDS
----   ---     --------
55     16      30
```

After playing arround with this code I resolved !!!

```
SELECT  SUM(DATEPART(hh, CAST(HORA_S AS DATETIME))) 
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(HORA_S AS DATETIME))) / 60 )
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(HORA_S AS DATETIME))) % 60
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(HORA_S AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) / 60 AS HORAS,
    ( SUM(DATEPART(MINUTE, CAST(HORA_S AS DATETIME))) % 60
        + ( SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(HORA_S AS DATETIME))) / 60 ) ) % 60 AS MINUTOS,
    SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CAST(HORA_S AS DATETIME))) % 60 AS SEGUNDOS FROM Table
```

Comment: not clear..could you please explain how u r arriving at the result?

Comment: Do you know any functions that might help calculating the difference between two dates? Have you tried to get the result in total seconds? Can you think of how you could get from seconds to minutes or hours? Hint: there are 60 seconds in a minute and 3600 seconds in an hour.

Comment: Do all of your `HORA_E` values happen on the same date (`1899-12-30`)?  Have you looked at using `DATEDIFF()` to get the total number of seconds, then use division and modulo to get your hours, minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example with a little less code

Sample table

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, HORA_S datetime)
insert @T values
(1, '1899-12-30 18:22:50.000'),
(2, '1899-12-30 18:22:50.000'),
(3, '1899-12-30 18:30:50.000')
```

---

```
;WITH T(V) AS (
    SELECT convert(datetime,SUM(convert(float, 2+hora_s)))
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    [HOURS]   = floor(convert(float,V)*24),
    [MINUTES] = DATEPART(MI,V),
    [SECONDS] = DATEPART(SS,V)
FROM T
```

Note: The 2+ in the query assumes that by `storing time only`, the date portion will always be `1899-12-30`. I know that Delphi uses that date as day `0`.